# Unable to see my files in SD card

Tags: android

I have created some text files in the SD card, but I am unable to view my files.

I am using this path `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`  to create files.

I am not getting any exception while creating files.

when I open the DDMS in eclipse I am unable to see my files there also..

If I created  the files at

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

then I can see my files at `/data` folder of the device , but not in SD card itself.

When I click on the gallery icon in my device, I can see only pictures, videos, camera shots folders only but not my files ..

please suggest is that the proper way of creating files in SD card.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()* doesn't always return the location to an external card. On android tablets (Android 3.0+) this directory is often mounted in the internal memory.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29):

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared
>   storage. It is a filesystem that can
>   hold a relatively large amount of data
>   and that is shared across all
>   applications (does not enforce
>   permissions). Traditionally this is an
>   SD card, but it may also be
>   implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the
>   protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

AFAIK there is no generic way to determine the mountpoint of an sdcard, this is specified by the device manufacturer. For example the ASUS Transformer mounts the external cards in */Removable/MicroSD* and */Removable/SD* . The "External Storage" directory */sdcard/* is mounted in internal space.